# Where does super-linear speedup come from?

Tags: language-agnostic, parallel-processing

In parallel computing theoretically super-linear speedup is not possible. But in practice we do see such cases. [One reason is cache effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedup#Super-linear_speedup) but I fail to understand what does it play. Also, there are other things involved but what are they? In summary,

> How are super-linear speedups possible?

I'm a beginner with respect to parallel computing.

Comment: Could you please add a link to the article you don't understand? Could you please quote a paragraph from an article you don't understand? Could you please rephrase what you understand from that paragraph, and pinpoint what you don't?

Comment: 1. At least provide a link to the source. 2. You are not asking a question here, simply stating that you fail to understand the source.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Suppose you have an 8 processor machine, each processor has a 1MB cache, and your computation uses 6MB of data.

On 1 processor the computation will be doing a lot of data movement between CPU, cache and RAM.  On 8 processors the computation will only have to move data between CPU and cache.  This way you can achieve super-linear speedup.

These figures and this analysis have been simplified for exposition for a beginner.

Comment: This is the shorter parallel algorithm performance analysis ever seen! :D

Comment: That does explain it but I'm confused, why on 8 processors you wouldn't need RAM?

Comment: @Ashish: once your computation has started and the 8 caches are each holding 6/8 MB of data then none of them need to empty or refill their caches during the computation.  Of course you still need RAM for a working computer, you just don't have to use it while this computation is running.  Pay careful attention to the last sentence of my answer.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: I was discussing this topic with a teacher, and he argued that the sequential algorithm could eventually chop the data in 8 pieces as the eight-core algorithm did, and sequentially solve each one. Then the amount of data transfers between memory hierarchies would be the same as for each node in the parallel solution. What do you think of that analysis, i could not prove the contrary so i had to accept his counter-example.

Answer (score 11):

In short, superlinear speedup is achieved when the total amount of work processors do is strictly less than the total work performed by a single processor.

This can happen in three ways:

- The original sequential algorithm was really bad, using the parallel version of the algorithm on one processor will usually do away with the superlinear speedup.
- The parallel algorithm uses some search like a random walk, the more processors that are walking, the less distance has to be walked in total before you reach what you are looking for.
- Modern processors have faster and slower memories. Typically it will try to keep the data you are using in the fast memory. We can safely say your amount of data is larger than the amount of fast memory. If you use n processors you have n times the amount of faster memory. More data fits in the fast memory which makes it possible to take less time (thus amount of work) on the same task.

Comment: So it's because parallel systems have more cache?

Comment: Not in general. But in a cluster, yes you do. If you look at architectures that try to scale well, coherent cache memory becomes unfeasible. What you get are many *simple* processors with a relatively tiny amount of cache, but very fast interconnections. You can see this in many parallel processors such as the CELL, GPUs, XMOS/transputer, TILERA and future cloud-on-a-chip peta-scale processors.

Comment: Addendum: the argument still holds in those systems, each core/processor still will have faster and slower memory. Meaning, more processors will still have more faster memory, even though you can't really call it cache.